# Android: Open settings when clicked

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out how to get a PreferencesActivity in Android to show up when the user clicks the default settings menu item.  I've followed this tutorial http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-quick-preferences-tutorial.html and it works well.  But the first thing that shows up is the settings page because of how the manifest is

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Now if I move that below my main activity (so MainAcivity is first) then MainActivity shows up first in my application, but I can't access QuickPrefsActivity through the menu.

Do I need to add a menu listener to be able to open QuickPrefsActivity?

Comment: I recommend you to add a onClickListener to your items in the menu... so once the item is clicked you create an intent to your next activity.

Comment: Thanks, I've implements onClickListener() in MainActivity now I'm just confused on how to start the view since it's not like a "standard" view

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.w(TAG, "onOptionsItemSelected");
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, QuickPrefsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need define code in Manifest like u mention here but just declare as normal Activity

like

```
<activity android:name="your.package.QuickPrefsActivity" />
```

and java code

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.settings) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, QuickPrefsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
}
```